# Display space between aura properties

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura-attribute

I use a custom label to display text in user language in my aura component.

My component has this line :

```
{!v.tr.Displaying} {!v.endUsersDisplayed} {!v.tr.users} {!v.tr.outof} {!v.totalNumberUsers}
```

I expect an output like `Displaying 12 users out of 50`, or `Affichage de 12 utilisateurs sur 50` if the user's language is french, but I have this ugly `Displaying12usersout of50`, the spaces being ignored.

I tried adding span tags like this :

```
<span>{!v.tr.Displaying}</span> <span>{!v.endUsersDisplayed}</span> <span>{!v.tr.users}</span> <span>{!v.tr.outof}</span> <span>{!v.totalNumberUsers}</span>
```

and also tu put the space in a span, but the output is always the same.

I sure can add the spaces in the label itself but I don't think it's clean.

Is there a way to have these spaces displayed, maybe a kind of sprintf function or something ? I've searched the doc but so far found nothing.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution after I wrote my question, I'll share it hre since I think that might help :
I replaced the line

```
{!v.tr.Displaying} {!v.endUsersDisplayed} {!v.tr.users} {!v.tr.outof} {!v.totalNumberUsers}
```

with

```
<aura:text value="{!v.tr.Displaying + ' ' + v.endUsersDisplayed + ' ' + v.tr.users + ' ' + v.tr.outof + ' ' + v.totalNumberUsers}
```

and I then got my expected output. A bit heavy imo but it works...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the join function to make the overall experience better:

```
{!join(' ', 
  v.tr.Displaying, 
  v.endUsersDisplayed, 
  v.tr.users, 
  v.tr.outof,
  v.totalNumberUsers)
}
```

The missing spaces occur due to how merge functions are compiled. This behavior is actually identical to how Visualforce removes spaces between consecutive merge fields and Visualforce elements (anything starting with `apex:`).

Answer (score 0):

The other ways to do it is html tag [&nbsp;](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp)

### Non-breaking Space

A commonly used entity in HTML is the non-breaking space:

A non-breaking space is a space that will not break into a new line.

Two words separated by a non-breaking space will stick together (not break into a new line). This is handy when breaking the words might be disruptive.

Comment: Thank you sanket kumar, I thought of this solution but a nbsp is not the same as a space so this solution has undesired effects. However if you don't need automatic line feeds, yes it shouls work.